# CSS - line-height issue

Tags: html, css

Watch the gap between `<h1>Jedálny lístok</h1>` and `<h2>A</h2>`

- What really makes the line-height attribute?
- Why `line-height: 1.5;` not equal to `line-height: 1.5em;`
- The gap is the same in both cases or a line-heigh destroyed that because without line-height are same...

With

```
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

[image: A]

Without

[image: B]

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Keyword values */
line-height: normal;

/* Unitless: use this number multiplied by the element's font size */ 
line-height: 3.5;

/* <length> values */
line-height: 3em;

/* <percentage> values */
line-height: 34%;

/* Global values */
line-height: inherit;
line-height: initial;
line-height: unset;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Syntax

Answer (score 0):

In the case of **inherited values**, line-height: 1.5 is not equal to line-height: 1.5em; For example if an inner element has twice the font size of its parent, then the inherited value 1.2 means that 1.2 times its own font size is used.